# Use Stripe API to return a list of valid subscribers

Tags: api, validation, parsing, curl, stripe-payments

Can someone please give some advice on the Stripe API. I want to use the stripe API and possibly some code to give me a filtered list of email addresses of 'valid subscribers' (i.e. subscribers who are paid up, and still have a valid subscription.

I'm using the following command to create a list of subscribers, however, this includes all subscribers (valid and invalid) and all of their details.

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers    -u sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: >> test4.txt
```

I believe the filter that indicates if the subscriber is valid or not is the following field is 'total count' in the following fields that are turned (1=valid, 0=invalid)

```
  "subscriptions": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 0,
```

The end result that I'm trying to achieve is a list of valid only subscribers in the format:

abc@hotmail.com
123@gmail.com
.....

Can anyone help please. The docs on the stripe site don't seem to cover this level of detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `curl` command:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers?subscription=true\&delinquent=false \
    -u sk_test_...
```

`subscription=true` will filter to return only customers with a subscription, and `delinquent=false` will further filter to return only customers who are paid up.

A few notes:

- these parameters are undocumented. They might change or break without warning.
- all "list" API calls only return a finite number of resources (by default, 10). You might need to issue several calls with [pagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api#pagination) parameters to retrieve the complete list of customers.
- it's not possible to tell `curl` to return only the email addresses. You could do this by piping the output to other command-line tools such as `grep`/`sed`/`awk` to format the output exactly as you need.